# Bugzilla Error : "Cannot determine local timezone"

Tags: ubuntu, timezone, bugzilla

After I installed Bugzilla on my LAN it works great... the problem is when I try to commit a bug it gives me an *internal error* "cannot determine local time zone"

I have searched far and wide on google and looks like a pretty wide spread problem on Ubuntu and debian boxes.

Please help.... I changed my server time zone, created a sym link to /etc/localtime ; I re-downloaded the perl modules... any thoughts?

thank you

Jared

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but this might help. There are a number of free virtual machines with pre-installed Bugzilla, including our own: http://almworks.com/vbs (Bugzilla version 3.2.2). Others may be found in the VMWare virtual marketplace. You can get a working Bugzilla in minutes after you install VMWare Player. So this might help if you just looking for a test Bugzilla server. Hope this helps.

Comment: What script or module is reported as the location of the error?  If it's not on the screen, check your server log to see what's happening.

Comment: Also, what version of Bugzilla?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently updated my version of Bugzilla and they have fixed the timezone error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using CPAN to install DateTime::TimeZone

```
cpan -i DateTime::TimeZone
```